# MySQL query to return unique values in one column and sorted by id to get a PHP array

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following simplified table: (Note we skipped 2nd exam in the `exam_id`)

```
+----+---------+-------+
| id | exam_id | score |
+----+---------+-------+
|  1 |    1    |   15  |
|  2 |    1    |   20  |
|  3 |    1    |   68  |
|  4 |    3    |   92  |
|  5 |    3    |   10  |
+----+---------+-------+
```

I want to write an `$sql` and some `php` (I'm using Wordpress, and can use `$wpdb`) to be able to get the following:

```
$exam[3]=10
$exam[1]=68
```

Not that when there are multiple exams, we take the `score` entry which corresponds to the largest `id`
And `$exam[2]` is empty. In words, I'd like to save the last ever exam that the user attempted and show their score.

I've tried using Group By and

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT
   *
FROM exams
WHERE exams.id IN (
                     SELECT
                        MAX(id)
                     FROM exams
                     GROUP BY exam_id
                  );
```

Comment: Thanks it works like a charm! Do you have an easy solution for php code by anychance? I'm thinking of getting it via $wpdb->get_results and then running a loop foreach($results as $result){$exam[$result->exam_id] = $result->score ;}